# Windows 7 and Server 08 network "location" changing

Tags: windows, windows-server-2008

Suddenly several domain computers running Windows 7 and at least one server on 2008 R2 are thinking that their NIC is part of a "public" network.  The weird part is that when this symptom occurs the domain machines are not able to access the internet in any way and nothing is able to access them.

Pinging any LAN resource succeeds but pinging any public address (ie 8.8.8.8) fails with General Failure error.

As soon as the "network location" is reset to private or work or whatever, everything works normally again.

Any ideas as to what might cause this?  It's a nightmare to change by hand.

Lastly, a "colleague" recently accessed this network and I have reason to believe he may have changed some thing or some number of things that may have caused this.  What might he have done?

Comment: For this type of problem it always makes sense to check DNS work. What do your domain clients use for DNS? What do the DC\DNS servers use for DNS?

Comment: Two internal DNS servers (both DCs as well) and Google DNS for public resolution.  DCs resolve public requests to Google and/or OpenDNS.

Comment: Can you clarify: What are the DNS client settings on your domain members and Domain Controllers? You're not using any public DNS servers in your DNS client settings, right? The Google DNS servers are configured as forwarders in your DNS server settings, right?

Comment: PCs look to two local DNS servers first for intranet resources.  The third DNS server on the PC is configured to public, typically Google.

Comment: I'm something of a network engineer tasked with a sysadmin role here - thanks for being patient and thanks for your help.

Comment: Here's what I would suggest as a first step: Remove the public DNS servers from the DNS client settings on all of the domain members. Make sure that the Domain Controllers are not using any public DNS servers in their DNS client settings. All of the domain members, including the Domain Controllers, should only have the AD DNS servers configured in their DNS client settings. Once you make those changes see if it resolves the issue.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/41561/discussion-between-tedwin-and-joeqwerty).